# Skip Soap Exception into Fork and Join Pattern

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Are currently I have a flow with an implementation "Fork and Join Pattern" where invoke the same service 5 times in parallel. When a service does not obtain this information return one soap fault. When I test the "Fork and Join" service this fails if one of the invocations is not satisfactory. How could ignore the exception (skip) of service that gets data to prevent failure of the main service?

This is my flow.

```
<mulexml:namespace-manager includeConfigNamespaces="true">
<mulexml:namespace prefix="sol" uri=".." />
</mulexml:namespace-manager>
```

Main Flow

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">        
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="3048"  doc:name="HTTP" path="path"/>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
    <logger message="step 1: #[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-session-variable variableName="var" value="#[message.payload.substring(message.payload.indexOf('string')+4,message.payload.indexOf('string')+16)]" doc:name="var"/>
    <set-variable variableName="var2" value="#[message.payload.substring(message.payload.indexOf('string')+4,message.payload.indexOf('string')+16)]" doc:name="svar"/> 
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="Class" doc:name="SOAP"/>
    <request-reply timeout="60000">
        <vm:outbound-endpoint path="parallel.processor.queue">
            <message-properties-transformer scope="outbound">
                <delete-message-property key="MULE_REPLYTO" />
            </message-properties-transformer>
        </vm:outbound-endpoint>
        <vm:inbound-endpoint path="join.queue" >      
        </vm:inbound-endpoint>
    </request-reply>
```

fork join flow

```
<flow name="fork_join_flow" doc:name="fork_join_flow">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="parallel.processor.queue" exchange-pattern="one-way" doc:name="VM"/>        
    <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE" value="5" doc:name="Property"/>
    <all doc:name="All">
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE"  value="1" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <flow-ref name="f1" doc:name="f1"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="2" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="f2" doc:name="f2"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="3" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="f3" doc:name="f3"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="4" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="f4" doc:name="f4"/>
        </async>
        <async doc:name="Async">
            <set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="5" doc:name="Property"/>
            <set-payload value="payload" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <flow-ref name="f5" doc:name="f5"/>
        </async>
    </all>
</flow>
```

Subflow - Web Services Invokers

```
<sub-flow name="f1" doc:name="f1">
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" address="http://localhost:1040/io/gob/ve/buscaTripletaPorSujeto">
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/xml" doc:name="Property"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="SOAP" operation="Operation" clientClass="Class" port="Port" wsdlLocation="wsdl"/>
    </http:outbound-endpoint>                        
    <custom-transformer class="Transformer" doc:name="tra" returnClass="Class"/>
    <set-variable variableName="var2" value="#[message:payload]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <flow-ref name="join1" doc:name="Flow Reference"/>
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="f2" doc:name="f2">
...
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="f3" doc:name="f3">
...
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="f4" doc:name="f4">
...
</sub-flow>

<sub-flow name="f5" doc:name="f5">
...
</sub-flow>
```

Join Flow

```
<sub-flow name="join1" doc:name="join1">
    <logger message="entro en join" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <collection-aggregator timeout="6000" failOnTimeout="true" doc:name="Collection Aggregator"/>
    <combine-collections-transformer />
    <logger level="INFO"  message="Continuing processing of: #[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <logger message="tipo de salida final: #[message:payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <scripting:transformer doc:name="Soap Response">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[
     import ...;
     import ...;
     import java.util.*;
     ICollection o = new ICollection();
     ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
     s = message.payload;
     println s[1].getM();
     o.setR(s[1].getI());
     o.setC(s.size());
     o.setS(message.payload);
     return o
  ]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:transformer>
    <vm:outbound-endpoint path="join.queue" doc:name="VM">              
    </vm:outbound-endpoint>
</sub-flow>
```

thanks for your help beforehand.